# Replace/Convert null value to empty array in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I have Pyspark dataframe:

```
id |  column_1       | column_2    | column_3
--------------------------------------------
1  |    ["12"]       |   null     |    ["67"]
--------------------------------------------
2  |    null         |   ["78"]    |   ["90"]
--------------------------------------------
3  |    ["""]        |  ["93"]     |   ["56"]
--------------------------------------------
4  |    ["100"]      |   ["78"]    |   ["90"]
--------------------------------------------
```

And I need to convert all `null` values for column1 to empty array `[]`

```
id |  column_1       | column_2    | column_3
--------------------------------------------
1  |    ["12"]       |   null     |    ["67"]
--------------------------------------------
2  |    []           |   ["78"]    |   ["90"]
--------------------------------------------
3  |    ["""]        |  ["93"]     |   ["56"]
--------------------------------------------
4  |    ["100"]      |   ["78"]    |   ["90"]
--------------------------------------------
```

Used this code, but it's not working for me.

```
df.withColumn("column_1", coalesce(column_1, array().cast("array<string>")))
```

Appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

The code working just fine for me, except that you need to wrap `column_1` into quotes `"column_1"`. Plus, you don't need to cast, just `array()` is enough.

```py
df.withColumn("column_1", coalesce('column_1', array()))
```

Comment: I don't think this will work, coalesce will throw an error saying different dtypes as input to coalesce, array and string, which is 'null'.